# reading excel sheet into spark dataframe - package issue

Tags: python, excel, azure, apache-spark

I've been trying to use the crealytics spark excel library, but without success.

Setup:
Databricks cluster running on Azure
Package installed from "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.3.1_0.18.7"
Scala version on cluster is 11.3.x-scala2.12

the code attempting to use this library is as simple as it gets:

```
sdf = spark.read.format("com.crealtyics.spark.excel").option("header","true").load(filepath)
```

However the error message is as follows:

> > Error when reading dbfs:/mnt/container/folder1/folder2/FileName.xlsx in as xlsx.   An error occurred while calling o627.load. :
> > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  Failed to find data source:
> > com.crealtyics.spark.excel. Please find packages at
> > https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

The package is installed as expected:[image: List of installed packages]

There is something simple and obvious missing here - but what is it?
Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the wasted question, but I've found a resolution and wanted to share it with anyone else facing a similar problem.  There's a lot of sites out there still pointing to the previous code which pointed to the Maven Repository.

With Spark-Excel V2 with data source API V2.0+, the reference to the Maven respository can be replaced with a reference to "excel".

```
sdf = spark.read.format("excel").option("header","true").load(filepath)
```

Further details here: https://index.scala-lang.org/crealytics/spark-excel
See under the heading *Features*

Comment: Not a wasted question! Will be useful if anyone else has this issue in the future. Thanks for posting your answer